# Passing parameter with-in grep command

Tags: bash, shell-script

How do I pass variables into a `grep` command? This hard-coded value is working:

```
startingLine=`grep -oP '(2017-01-03 )\w+.+' cv-batch.log | head -1`
echo $startingLine
```

But when I try to use a variable, it stops working:

```
currDate=$(date -d "$dataset_date" +%Y-%m-%d)
echo $currDate
startingLine=`grep -oP '($currDate )\w+.+' cv-batch.log | head -1`
```

**Edit**: I tried the following but it didn't work either:

```
startingLine=`grep -oP '("$currDate" )\w+.+' cv-batch.log | head -1`
```

Comment: use double quotes

Comment: I tried   command but it did not worked. Please see update #1 in this question

Comment: For the whole `grep` command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable isn't "passed" since it's in single quotes.  The shell will not do variable expansion within single quotes. Use double quotes instead to have the shell expand the variable's value before calling `grep`:

```
startingLine="$( grep -oP "($currDate )\w+.+" cv-batch.log | head -1)"
```

Notice that the *variable* is never actually "passed" to `grep`, but that it's its expanded value that is used when the shell executes the utility.  Try running this by first enabling tracing (`set -x`) to see what actually goes on when you run it (disable tracing with `set +x` afterwards).

I've also used the more robust (and better looking) command substitution syntax `$( ... )`, and quoted the whole resulting string to avoid any problems with file name globbing and word splitting.

You should also double quote the `$currDate` in the `echo`:

```
echo "$currDate"
```

or

```
printf '%s\n' "$currDate"
```

See

- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells), and
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)